# Excel: How to sum dataset with 3 levels of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum the third level of a data set based on data on first level, as described below (**using Excel 2013**).

[image: Excel Print]

In the image above, the dataset shows 3 levels:

- Column C is the "FK" for A.
- Column D is "FK" for B.

I want to sum column E based on column A.

For now, I write the following formula:

`=SUMIF($E$3:$E$12; $D$3:$D$12; INDEX($B$3:$B$12;MATCH($G$3;$C$3:$C$12;0)))`

This formula looks like works, but the MATCH just returns one result.

I also tried another options like this one:

`=SUMIFS($E$3:$E$12; $D$3:$D$12; INDEX($B$3:$B$12; IF($C$3:$C$12=$G$3;$B$3:$B$12;"")))`

The part below, suppose to retrieve lines 4 and 5, but, again, just returns one result:

`INDEX($B$3:$B$12; IF($C$3:$C$12=$G$3;$B$3:$B$12;""))`

Is there any way to do that without external resources?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean you would like to sum column E based on column A? Can you elabolare a bit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by external resources.  Does your formula gives the right answer?

Comment: I think by external resources he means column G in his picture...

Comment: Is `16` the answer you are looking for?  If so, why?  should it not be `19`?

Comment: @sophods, see the image on link to better understand (my account have no rights to embed the image here).

Comment: Scott, the right answer is 19, as you said. But the MATCH formula only return the first cell on column B (value E) and on column D, only the lines 9 and 10 were used. But the correct is on column B retrieve the lines 6 and 7 (values E and F) and then on column D retrieves lines 9 to 11 (values 9+7+3 = 19).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,B6:B8)*(C6:C8=G3))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! Amazing. It works very nice. Thanks a lot! I just adapt to get the entire "dataset", because I have a bunch of data and is not possible to select the specific range: =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(E3:E12,D3:D12,B3:B12)*(C3:C12=G3))